# ASP.NET MVC- functionalities of a view doesn't work unless I access it directly

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with sidebar that contains a list of files, and a partial view contains a text area. I want to display the contents of a file once the user clicks on it (by refreshing the partial view). This is the script I'm using:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.filelist').on('click', function (e) {
             var filePath = $(this).attr('value');    //value is attribute set in Html
             $('#partial').load('DevelopmentPartial', { path1: filePath });
         });
     });
</script>
```

It was working correctly until yesterday, I started getting this error when redirecting to this view, but not if it was accessed directly:

> The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by
>   the static file handler

I was able to get rid of the error, but now the functionalities like displaying the contents of the files on-click doesn't work unless I access the 
view directly, but if I redirect to it from another action method it doesn't!

**This is my controller:**

```
 StudentsCodes modelSC;

    public DevelopmentController()
    {
        m4 = new MicroG4();
        modelSC = new StudentsCodes();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        modelSC.Student = (Student)CurrentUser;
        var user = UserManager.FindById(((Student)CurrentUser).InstructorID);
        modelSC.Instructor =(Instructor) user;
        //modelSC.path = "~/Content/" + CurrentUser.UserName + "/CompilerProject/src/Driver.java";
         return View(modelSC);
    }
    public PartialViewResult DevelopmentPartial(string path1)
    {
        modelSC.Student = (Student)CurrentUser;
        var user = UserManager.FindById(((Student)CurrentUser).InstructorID);
        modelSC.Instructor = (Instructor)user;
        modelSC.path = path1;
        modelSC.code = "";
        if (modelSC.path == null)
        {
            modelSC.code = "";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
               modelSC.code = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(modelSC.path));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                modelSC.code = "";
            }
        }
        return PartialView(modelSC);

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you drop this script into the main view page instead of the partial view

Comment: This script is in the main view, it calls the partial view.

Comment: guess that you checked the console window to give you a hint on what was going on!

Comment: Actually, this is my fist website, I just kept trying, I don't know how to troubleshoot problems yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reordering the scripts in the main view as the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

The *jquery.unobtrusive* was the first. Then I updated the script that loads the partial view :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.filelist').on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             alert('Im clicked on filePath = ' + $(this).attr('value'));
             var filePath = $(this).attr('value');    //value is attribute set in Html
             $('#partial').load('@Url.Action("DevelopmentPartial", "Development")', { path1: filePath });
         });
     });
</script>
```